# UITableView run error in xCode 6.1 IOS 8

Tags: ios, uitableview

Please see my code below, runs in Xcode 6.1 IOS 8 failed, it report error below:
Type "ViewController" doesn't conform to Protocol "UITableViewDataSource"

Could anyone help to have a look what is the problem is? Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    var tableView = UITableView()
    var items: NSMutableArray = ["row 0","row 1","row 2","row 3","row 4"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 530)
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 90/255, green: 31/255, blue: 10/255, alpha: 0.2)
 //   tableView.style = UITableViewStyle.Grouped
    tableView.rowHeight = 50
    tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.SingleLine

    //self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

   // tableView.delegate = self

   // tableView.dataSource = self


   self.view.addSubview(tableView)


}
//UITableViewDataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    //println("Hello \(indexPath.row)")
   var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("my cell id") as? UITableViewCell

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "my cell id")
    }

    //cell.textLabel?.text = listOfViewControllers[indexPath.row]
    //cell!.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row] as String
    //var s = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
    var s = items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as String
    cell!.textLabel?.text = s
    return cell
}

//UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: have you attached datasource and delegate with viewcontroller?

Comment: uncomment  // tableView.delegate = self

   // tableView.dataSource = self

Comment: Uncomment this don't works, same error exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with this method signature, it is not similar to the one defined in the [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
```

Change that to:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you mean change to this? a blank after _underline, this will cause compile error.  If no this blank the problem still exist.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

Comment: @AlexZhu Replace your existing declaration with the one provided in the answer. Please check the updated declaration

Comment: Thanks! Also added ! here:   return cell!
then compile successfully.
But there is no data in table view. Seems this func are not executed, I added a println and see it is not executed.

Comment: Thank you, but there is no data which defined in Arr items at first, could you please kindly check...

Comment: @AlexZhu: Your code looks ok to me, check whether the issue is with tableview color you added if that's the case then add color to your label, also check that the textLabel is not nil.

Comment: Too strange, I added println("222") in anywhere in this func but it will all not be executed. I am not sure how to check textLabel nil or not, I will reboot MAC and xCode to see if there is problem. Thank you for your patience.